# Reference JSPM packages within HTML without the version in path

Tags: javascript, gulp, jspm

I am trying to reference the stylesheet for bootstrap ans some JS files from jspm_packages folder.

```
<link href="~/jspm_packages/npm/tether@1.3.2/dist/css/tether.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/jspm_packages/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What's bothering me is there are versions in the path and it may break once I update with a newer version later. I am using JSPM as my frontend package manager and totally replaced Bower with it. With bower, I don't encounter these versions in the path.

Is there a way to reference them without the version? I am thinking of gulping to a different directory but that would require specifying each dependency path in gulpfile and will also cause duplication.